# What set is this brown (wall?) element from?

Tags: part-identification

While sorting out some old Lego finds, I stumbled across this piece:

[image: This piece confuses me]

I have *absolutely* no idea what this element could be for other than some kind of wall part, and even then I have never seen anything like it before. It is the same colour as some "wooden" elements I have,but I honestly have no clue.

Any information about the piece and any set(s) it was present in would be great.

Comment: It's a Swivelling Door element, allowing for Skeletons to "pop out" and scare the knights ;) You can see a similar element in use here: http://www.peeron.com/scans/9376-1/7/

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid Yes I now see that, very cool. But sadly, I can't seem to find the door-frame to make this work. :(

Comment: Keep rummaging, it might be in there :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like this [piece](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=30102); Door 2 x 5 x 5 Swivel, Flat Base.

[image: Door 2 x 5 x 5 Swivel, Flat Base]

In this case it was part of LEGO Set 6089, [Stone Tower Bridge](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?S=6089-1).

[image: pic of stone tower bridge]

Comment: Thanks, that should be the piece and, from looking at other pieces that were mixed with it (that I thought _totally_ unrelated), it definitely looks like that was the set it came from.

Answer (score 6):

This piece has also been used recently, in some of the Harry Potter sets.

Here, in the gaudily-coloured "Gryffindor" Set (4722-1) with the portrait of the Fat Lady.
[image]

And also here, in "The Final Challenge", (4702-1) where it appears as The Mirror of Erised.
[image]